# in which situation very simple query sql could be slow sql

Tags: mysql

Latest my company had a promotion activity and had high QPS, after the activity, did some summary. I saw a very simple query sql among top 3 slow sql.

```
select config_key, value from system_config where config_key = 'XXX';
```

And the total count of the table less than 100.

I'm very confused, I think either it cannot be executed because connection is full or executed very soon, It will not be a slow sql.

So in which situation like this simple query sql could be slow sql?

Comment: Did you check if the tables indexes were set correctly?

Comment: Also mysql offers an "optimization" command for tables, you should execute it now and then.

Comment: And obviously the table might be locked by other queries.

Comment: @zhuguowei - Post us the output from **EXPLAIN select * from system_config where config_key = 'XXX';**

Comment: And don't use evil 'SELECT *'. Always name the columns you want returned.